# Modify only enabled checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have the below piece of code, whereby $(obj) is the main checkbox (select all/deselect all).
The function is working successfully, however I want to restrict the functionality to only enabled checkboxes.
Some checkboxes are disabled and I don't want it to be affected by the functionality.
Any idea on how to do so?

```
 if( $(obj).is(':checked') ) {
        $("#scrollableContent input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
    }else {
        $("#scrollableContent input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery selector [`:enabled`](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) :

```
$("#scrollableContent input[type='checkbox']:enabled").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are selectors to get only disabled elements `:disabled` or enabled elements `:enabled`

```
if( $(obj).is(':checked') ) {
    $("#scrollableContent input[type='checkbox']:not(:disabled)").prop("checked", true);
}else {
    $("#scrollableContent input[type='checkbox']:not(:disabled)").prop("checked", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the others, you can use `:not` selector, but you can also refactor your code into one line:

```
$("#scrollableContent input[type='checkbox']:not(:disabled)").prop("checked", $(obj).is(':checked'));
```

Or, using jQuery's `not()`:

```
 $("#scrollableContent input[type='checkbox']").not(':disabled').prop("checked", $(obj).is(':checked'));
```